Tensor functors on rigid categories.
Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ and $(\mathcal{C}',\otimes')$ be rigid tensor categories (in the sense of Deligne/Milne; see https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2022.pdf). My question is asked in the context of page $11$ in ibid. Let $\text{ev}_{X,Y}:\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y) \otimes X \to Y$ correspond to $\text{id}_{\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)}$ under the natural isomorphism $$\text{Hom}(\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y),\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)) \simeq \text{Hom}(\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y) \otimes X,Y).$$
Then if $(F,c)$ is a pair where $F$ is a tensor functor $F:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}'$ and $c_{X,Y}:F(X) \otimes F(Y) \xrightarrow[]{\simeq} F(X \otimes Y)$ are natural isomorphisms, then it is claimed that $F(\text{ev}_{X,Y}):F(\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)) \otimes F(X) \to F(Y)$ gives rise to morphisms $F_{X,Y}:F(\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)) \to \underline{\text{Hom}}(FX,FY)$.
Now, I assume that they by $F(\text{ev}_{X,Y})$ they really mean $F(\text{ev}_{X,Y})$ composed with some natural isomorphism $c_{X,Y}$, since the domain of $F(\text{ev}_{X,Y})$ naively interpreted is not the same as their definition.
I am interested in understanding in which way we get morphisms $F_{X,Y}:F(\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)) \to \underline{\text{Hom}}(FX,FY)$?

They write that you get a morphism $F(\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y))\to\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(FX,FY)$, not a morphism with target $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y)$. This morphism $F(\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y))\to\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(FX,FY)$ is obtained via the tensor-hom adjunction from the morphism $F(\mathrm{ev}_{X,Y})\colon F(\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y))\otimes FX\to FY$. (It is by the way standard to omit the isomorphisms $c_{X,Y}$ from the notation, as they are canonical and otherwise just cluttering up the notation.)
Edit: I will write out why the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y)) @>{F_{X,Y}}>> \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(FX,FY)\\
@A{\alpha}AA @AA{\beta}A\\
F(X^\vee\otimes Y) @>{\gamma}>> (FX)^\vee\otimes FY 
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, where the vertical maps are the canonical isomorphisms of this type, and the bottom map is the map you have shown to be an isomorphism. By the tensor-hom adjunction, it suffices to show that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
FX\otimes F(\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y)) @>{F(\mathrm{ev})}>> FY\\
@A{FX\otimes\alpha}AA @AA{\varepsilon_{FX}\otimes FY}A\\
FX\otimes F(X^\vee\otimes Y) @>{FX\otimes \gamma}>> FX\otimes (FX)^\vee\otimes FY
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, where $\varepsilon_{-}\colon (-)\otimes(-)^\vee\to \mathbf{1}$ is the evaluation map that a duality datum comes with. You have checked that $\varepsilon_{FX}$ is the map $FX\otimes(FX)^\vee\cong F(X\otimes X^\vee)\xrightarrow{F\varepsilon_X}F(\mathbf{1})\cong\mathbf{1}$. Therefore, the map in the square given by first going right and then going up is just the map
$$
FX\otimes F(X^\vee\otimes Y)\cong FX\otimes F(X^\vee)\otimes FY\cong F(X\otimes X^\vee)\otimes FY\xrightarrow{F\varepsilon_X\otimes FY}FY. 
$$
On the other hand, the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\otimes\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y) @>{\mathrm{ev}}>> Y\\
@AAA @AA{\mathrm{id}}A\\
X\otimes X^\vee \otimes Y @>{\varepsilon_X\otimes Y}>> Y
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, because $X^\vee\otimes -\cong\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,-)$ as functors. Therefore, both are adjoint to $X\otimes -$, and in particular the counits agree under the natural isomorphism. This is exactly what the above diagram says. If I apply $F$ to the commutative diagram above, I find that in the second square, the map $F(\mathrm{ev})\circ(FX\otimes\alpha)$ is given by
$$
FX\otimes F(X^\vee\otimes Y)\cong F(X\otimes X^\vee\otimes Y)\xrightarrow{F(\varepsilon_X\otimes Y)} FY.
$$
This is the same as what we wrote down for the map $(\varepsilon_{FX}\otimes FY)\circ(FX\otimes \gamma)$, because of the ways the isomorphisms $F(A\otimes B)\cong FA\otimes FB$ and $A\otimes(B\otimes C)\cong (A\otimes B)\otimes C$ are required to interact.

Ops, yes, that was a typo.

I see now that I did actually write down precisely what you wrote, I must somehow have forgotten this. Thanks a lot.
A follow up question; do you have an explanation for why this must be an isomorphism? I did not completely understand the reasoning in Deligne/Milne (I am quite new to this area).

By rigidity, $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,Y)\cong X^\vee\otimes Y$, and similarly $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(FX,FY)\cong (FX)^\vee\otimes FY$. Since $F$ preserves tensors, to show the isomorphism it suffices to assume $Y\cong\mathbf{1}$ and prove the result in that case. This is the statement that the given map $F(X^\vee)\to (FX)^\vee$ is an isomorphism, i.e. that $F$ preserves duality, and this is what they show. They list what a duality data is and its properties, and all of these properties are preserved by $F$ since it is a functor and preserves the tensor.

Hm, thanks a lot Daniël, let me mull this over =)

Okay, now I believe I have figured out everything you say, or that is, I have showed everything we talked about (for myself, I do not write it out here). Now, one sees that (I believe; first isomorphism which follows is since functors preserve isomorphisms) $F(\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y) \cong F(X^{\vee}) \otimes ' F(Y) = F(X)^{\vee} \otimes' Y$ and we also saw that $\underline{\text{Hom}}(FX,FY) \cong F(X)^{\vee} \otimes' F(Y)$. So this means that the domain and codomain are isomorphic in $\mathcal{C}'$. I am still not seeing why $F_{X,Y}$ must be such an isomorphism.

@Ben123 I edited an explanation for that in the answer.

So I suppose your $\varepsilon$ is $\text{ev} \circ \psi$ in Deligne/Milne, where $\psi$ is the commutator. Yeah, tbh, I think I am more confused now, and this is not really how I think about this.

Perhaps some of my confusion stems from the fact that I am not quite comfortable with adjunctions, although I aspire to be.
