Dual functor in symmetric monoidal categories respect composition.
Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a rigid symmetric monoidal category. Why is it then the case that the dualizing map $X \mapsto X^{\vee}$ is a functor on morphisms so that it respects composition? I know how to show that ${}^{t}(\text{id}_{X}) = \text{id}_{X^{\vee}}$, but I don't know how to show that ${}^{t}(g \circ f) = {}^{t}f \circ {}^{t}g$ for morphisms $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$. I tried to use the snake-equation and the fact that (for arbitrary morphism $f$), ${}^{t}f := (\text{ev} \otimes \text{id}) \circ (\text{id} \otimes f \otimes \text{id}) \circ (\text{id} \otimes \epsilon)$, where $\text{ev}$ is evaulation-map, and $\epsilon$ is the counit/coevaulation map that duality data comes with, but then we get
\begin{align*}
{}^{t}f \circ {}^{t}g = (\text{ev}_Y \otimes \text{id} \circ \text{id} \otimes f \otimes \text{id} \circ \text{id} \otimes \epsilon_{X}) \circ (\text{ev}_{Z} \otimes \text{id} \circ \text{id} \otimes g \otimes \text{id} \circ \text{id} \otimes \epsilon_{Y})
\end{align*}
and I don't know how to show that this equals $(g \circ f)^{t}$.
Would be glad for any clarification. There already is a question here: Composition of Dual Maps in (rigid) Monoidal Categories but without answers. I am interested in a non-string diagrammatic explanation.

Why are you using two different notations $^tf$ and $f^\vee$?

I am just following (I believe) the convention in Milne/Deligne. This is how they define the "morphism" (morphism in the functor category) $X \mapsto X^{\vee}$ on morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$. Perhaps I am mistaken.

They seem to exclusively use $X^\vee$ for objects and $^tf$ for morphisms, but you've also used $(g \circ f)^\vee$ for morphisms. Just nitpicking.

Let me change it, thanks for pointing it out.
Edit: I have changed it. Do you know how to show this @NaïmFavier?

Sorry, my previous (deleted) comment was wrong: you need to use naturality to slide the two sides of the $\circ$ past each other, then use the snake identity in the middle. This is much easier to see using string diagrams.

Honestly, I have not invested much time in understanding string-diagrams in any depth, and when I have tried, I feel like the author usually slips some explanations under the rug when they suddenly do more advanced computations.
With regard to your comment; naturality of what? The evaluation/coevaluation? hmm, right, that might work, let me think about it.

This is essentially a big calculation involving naturality that is completely obvious to check as a string diagram: you slide the two blocks past each other and apply the snake identity in the middle.
Since you asked for a proof without string diagrams, here is a regular diagram. I've omitted the morphisms that are evaluations or coevaluations. Every square is functoriality of $\otimes$ and the "triangle" on the bottom is a snake identity.


Wow, thanks a lot. Is the map (in the lower left corner) from $Z^{} \otimes Y \otimes X^{}$ to $Z^{} \otimes Y \otimes Y^{} \otimes Y \otimes X$ the map $(\text{id} \otimes \text{id} \otimes (\psi \circ \mathrm{coev}) \otimes \text{id}) \circ (\text{id} \otimes r_{Y} \otimes \text{id}) $ (using Delinge/Milnes notation, i.e. $r_Y:Y \leadsto Y \otimes \mathbf{1}$ and $\psi$ is the commutator)?

No commutators involved; it's $Z^* \otimes \epsilon_Y \otimes Y \otimes X^*$ (omitting associators and unitors).

Oh, yes, ofc! thnx

Wait, I am however somethat confused. Naturality of what exactly? The evaluation/coevaluation are just morphisms? Or do they assemble (in rigid categories) into a natural transformation where one of the functors is the constant functor at the identity object and the other functor the "obvious one" (i.e. for $\mathrm{coev}$ it is $A \leadsto A \otimes A^*$)?

That would be circular, as you'd need to have the functor $-^*$ already defined to talk about such a natural transformation. By naturality I really mean the functoriality of $\otimes$, i.e. the fact that $(f \otimes \mathrm{id}) \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes g) = (\mathrm{id} \otimes g) \otimes (f \otimes \mathrm{id})$. You can see this as the naturality of $f \otimes \mathrm{id}_- : A \otimes - \to B \otimes -$. More generally, naturality is functoriality of functors $I \times A \to B$ (see here)

Okay, I think I understand now. I wanted to share a quiver-diagram to check my sanity, but the link is to large (word-wise) for a comment. Thanks for clarifying!

There is another theorem of Deligne/Milne I don't understand, if you would allow me to ask about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4932465/tensor-functors-on-rigid-categories
I don't fully understand the answer given there, although I do understand parts of it, I don't understand it completely. I do know how to show that duality is preserved (see e.g. "Categories for Quantum Theory", chapter 3, by C. Heunen et al., iirc), but I don't understand why this is enough (according to Delinge/Milne).

Could you ask it as a separate question? I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

I am not sure that is alright with the moderators? I mean, I would be asking essentially the same question as in the link above.

The proof strategy in Catégories Tannakiennes is to show that the induced maps $F_{X,\mathbf{1}}$ are isomorphisms.  Then diagram 4.3.3.2 (chapter I) in ibid. shows that $F_{X,Y}$ is an isomorphism. So it essentially reduces to showing that the induced maps $F_{X,\mathbf{1}}$ are isomorphisms, and that  4.3.3.2 in ibid. commutes. AFAICT, S. Rivano does not show why 4.3.3.2 commutes.

I asked a question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475757/diagram-4-3-3-2-i-in-cat%c3%a9gories-tannakiennes-by-s-rivano
